# Break one column into several columns everytime you see a pattern

Tags: bash, awk

I have a quite simple question, but I find it hard to solve this problem.
I have two quite long column of data, and i want to separate it into several columns. the script should start writing data into a new column, each time it finds a specific string in the first column:
input:

```
A B
1 C 
2 C
3 C
4 C
A D
1 D
2 D
3 D
4 D
```

output:

```
A B    A D
1 C    1 D
2 C    2 D
3 C    3 D
4 C    4 D
```

(the separating pattern is A)

Answer (score 1):

awk with paste:

```
$ awk '$1 == "A" { ++n } { print > ("t.tmp." n) }' input.txt
$ ls t.tmp.*
t.tmp.1 t.tmp.2
$ paste t.tmp.*
A B     A D
1 C     1 D
2 C     2 D
3 C     3 D
4 C     4 D
```

**EDIT**

More efficient (only build the file name once for each group) and more robust (avoid the chance of having too many open files by closing them as we go) --- thanks, Ed Morton:

```
awk '$1 == "A" { close(out); out = "t.tmp." ++n} { print > out }' input.txt
```

(Above assumes first record contains pattern. If not, can initialize out in a BEGIN block.)

Comment: Agreed, @EdMorton, answer updated with improved version. I also see from the docs that it's harmless to call close with an argument that doesn't correspond to an open file, which is good to know in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using single `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>1 && /^A/{p=1} {if (p) print a[++i], $0; else a[NR]=$0}' OFS='\t' file

A B     A D
1 C     1 D
2 C     2 D
3 C     3 D
4 C     4 D
```

Comment: Yes good point, no need to make it complicated. It is edited now.

Answer (score 1):

Using `csplit` and `paste`

```
$ csplit -zsf file infile.txt '/A/' {*}
$ paste file*
A B     A D
1 C     1 D
2 C     2 D
3 C     3 D
4 C     4 D
```

From `man csplit`

> csplit - split a file into sections determined by context lines
>
> -z, --elide-empty-files
>   remove empty output files
>
> -s, --quiet, --silent
>   do not print counts of output file sizes
>
> -f, --prefix=PREFIX
>   use PREFIX instead of 'xx'
>
> {*}    repeat the previous pattern as many times as possible

Answer (score -1):

using gnu awk multiline records - works for any number of occurrences of pattern - assumes equal length columns

```
pat=A
awk -vpat=$pat -F'\n' '
BEGIN {RS="(^|\n)"pat" "}
NR>1{
  nr=NR-2
  fld[nr][0]=pat" "$1
  for(i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
    fld[nr][i-1]=$i
}
END {
  for(i=0; i < NF; ++i) {
    for(j=0; j < NR-1; ++j)
      printf("%s%s", j?"\t":"", fld[j][i])
    printf("\n")
  }
}
'
```

input

```
A B
1 C
2 C
3 C
4 C
A D
1 D
2 D
3 D
4 D
A X
1 X
3 X
5 X
7 X
```

output

```
A B     A D     A X
1 C     1 D     1 X
2 C     2 D     3 X
3 C     3 D     5 X
4 C     4 D     7 X
```

Answer (score -3):

If you're reading this and wondering why it got downvoted, it's just some clown being childish because I pointed out some problems with and ways they could improve their previous answer, the downvote has nothing to do with the technical merits of this answer. This is **the** idiomatic awk solution to this problem.

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '
    $1 == "A" { numRows=0; ++numCols }
    { val[++numRows,numCols] = $0 }
    END {
        for (rowNr=1;rowNr<=numRows;rowNr++) {
            for (colNr=1;colNr<=numCols;colNr++) {
                printf "%s%s", val[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
            }
        }
    }
' file
A B     A D
1 C     1 D
2 C     2 D
3 C     3 D
4 C     4 D
```